# How do I convert the radio values html into a textfile

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a quiz generator using html and javascript where the teacher/user inputs the question with 4 radio button inputs, and the selected radio value will be the correct answer.

But I have to convert everything into a text file so that another team of people can upload it to their program

The code I have is:

```
            Enter Question 16: <input type="text" name="question16"><br>
    <br>
Next, add a correct answer and several incorrect answers for your question.
<br>
<form>
  <p>
  <input type="radio" name="choice62" value="62">
  <label><input size="50"></label></p>
  <p>
  <input type="radio" name="choice63" value="63">
  <label><input size="50"></label></p>
  <p>
  <input type="radio" name="choice64" value="64`enter code here`">
  <label><input size="50"></label></p>
  <p>
  <input type="radio" name="choice65" value="65">
  <label><input size="50"></label></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the question text and values from the radio buttons, format and store the values you want to save in a string variable then you can use the function below to save the string (variable) as a text file:

```
function saveAsText(text) {

    var blob = new Blob([text], { type: "text/plain" });
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    var filename = "myFileName.txt";      
    anchor.download = filename;
    anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    anchor.target = "_blank";
    anchor.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);

}
```